# How can I configure MyGeneration tool to run the code template for each table and create .cs file for each?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, mygeneration

How can I configure MyGeneration conde-generator tool to run the code template for each Db table and create a separate .cs for each?

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the template and select all tables from the list (it is multi-Select).or you need to write a **template** for this.

for template writing , check the forum [Here](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/phpbb3/index.php) specially template forums (last three ones) .or try to make self learning by opening  an existing template such as : **CSharp_SQL_dOOdads_BusinessEntity.vbgen** you will find code such as :

```
Sub bindTables(sDatabase)
    Set db = MyMeta.Databases(sDatabase)
    lstTables.BindData(db.Tables)
End Sub
```

I dont know , if you can make a for loop on "db.Tables" and doing whatever for each table .
also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520596/is-it-possible-to-have-intellisense-support-in-mygeneration-when-it-comes-to-writ) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519870/how-can-i-achieve-this-simple-output-in-mygeneration)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701626/can-you-recommend-a-step-by-step-tutorial-on-developing-c-code-templates-with-my) and [this template library](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/TemplateLibrary/Articles/)